# How to work concurrently with terraform on the same "workspace"?

Tags: terraform

Assume the following scenario. There's one remote workspace that needs to be configured with terraform. Since there're multiple subtasks there are different persons working on them, concurrently. There's a single git repo and devops are working with branching approach. There's also a remote state configured for terraform. Now, consider the following scenario:

- `devops1` introduces some changes and applies them, then issues a PR
- `devops2` who is working on a different task cannot apply/test his/her changes because of the remote state being already modified by `devops1` and not having this changes locally in the code (PR was not accepted and merged yet)

How this scenario can be addressed in the way other for having separate workspaces? What else comes to my mind is that all the changes to the remote state should be revoked before issuing a PR and applied after it's merged.

Anything else?

Comment: Apply before creating a PR? What is the purpose of the PR then? Wouldn't having a CI/CD pipeline for this be more prudent?

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks for the input. I thought about it, however don't know whether we have CI/CD for TF here. Will ask and probably this is the way to go.

Comment: Just thinking out loud. :)